# Deserialization Error while returning the Object from WCF Service

Tags: wcf

I'm getting below shown error while returning the Activity object array.Not able understand where things are going wrong.Can any one help me with this .

Here is the error

> End element 'ActivityTypeId' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusinessEntities' expected.
>   Found element 'a:Code' from namespace
>   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/BusinessEntities'. Line 1,
>   position 450.

UI Related code:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeSheetManagementServiceClient serviceClient = new TimeSheetManagementServiceClient("WSHttpBinding_ITimeSheetManagementService");
        Activity[] activities=serviceClient.GetActivities();
        GridView1.DataSource = activities;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }
```

WCFService code

```
 public class TimeSheetManagementService:ITimeSheetManagementService 
    {
        public BusinessEntities.Activity[] GetActivities()
        {
            TimeSheetManagementDataController controller= new TimeSheetManagementDataController();
            var activities = controller.GetActivities().Select(activity => new BusinessEntities.Activity()
                                                                               {
                                                                                   Code = activity.Code,
                                                                                   Description = activity.Description,
                                                                                   Status =
                                                                                       (EntityStatus)
                                                                                       Enum.Parse(typeof(EntityStatus), ((activity.Status==true) ? 0 : 1).ToString()),
                                                                                   ActivityTypeId = new BusinessEntities.ActivityType()
                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                          Code=activity.ActivityType.Code,
                                                                                                          Description = activity.ActivityType.Description,
                                                                                                          Name = activity.ActivityType.Name
                                                                                                        }


                                                                               });
            return activities.ToArray();
        }

    }
```

Service Contract

```
  [ServiceContract]
    interface ITimeSheetManagementService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Activity[] GetActivities();
    }
```

Data Contract

```
[DataContract]
public class Activity
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public EntityStatus Status { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ActivityType  ActivityTypeId { get; set; }
}
[DataContract]
public enum EntityStatus
{
    [EnumMember]
    Active=0,
    [EnumMember]
    Inactive=1
}

[DataContract]
public class ActivityType
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Code { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description { get; set; }


}
```

Comment: Some how i found the solution to this issue, Return type of GetActivities method changed to List<Activity> and instead of returning array, i'm returing List. After making this change this code worked as expected.But not sure about the reason for the issue. Please let me know if anybody have any idea about this behaviour.

Comment: please add your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted so that others will know that this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

i`m not sure but i think the issue is the alphabetical order of the datamember of your Activity class. just for testing, consider specifying the order property in the Datamember attribute.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729813%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

hope this will help

Comment: i feel some thing to do with ActivityTypeId, it worked when this property was string or Guid. but when i changed it to be a class then this issue started.